# Preview the DOF result in a D5100 viewfinder?

Tags: depth-of-field, nikon-d5100, viewfinder, preview

I have been told that some cameras have the ability to show the exact Depth of Field in the viewfinder when pressing a button.

I searched for that button on my `Nikon D5100` without success. I could not find any other alternative to achieve the same goal.

I would be very interested to learn if/how this could be done.

Comment: You might want to pull your edit out as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. The D5100 does not have a Depth-of-field preview functionality. If you take a look at the [list of Nikon DSLRs](http://www.neocamera.com/list_cameras.php?brand=nikon&status=current&type=slr), the one with the icons in the shape of an iris have that feature. The D7000 just below the D5100 on the list has it. Typically, this function does not make it into entry-level cameras.

The best you can do it take a test shot and zoom on on your display to see the depth-of-field you got.

Comment: Entry level cameras from Canon and Nikon lack many nice features, while smaller brands like Sony and Pentax often have these. For example even the cheapest Sony SLT model has DoF preview button.